# Read raw data from memory card on linux

Tags: c, memory, raw-data

I want to read allocation unit 512b from memory card using c on Linux os,
how can I open  (raw data) of the memory card using (fopen)?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post your attempt so far and where you've run into trouble specifically. See [mcve] for more guidelines about what's on topic, and visit [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for additional tips.

Comment: In linux all devices are files, so if you use linux you may be able to do it by using `fopen()` on `/dev/whatever`.  I didn't try though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> on Linux [...] how can I open (raw data) of the memory card using (fopen)?

Supposing that the operating system recognizes the card's presence, it will present the card to user programs as a device file.  On my system, for example, that is typically `/dev/sdb`, but it could easily be different on yours (and even on mine, for various reasons).  Provided that you have sufficient privilege, you can open the appropriate file and read data from it just as you do an ordinary file.  Relying only on standard C functions, then, one might do this:

```
unsigned char data[512];
FILE *card = fopen("/dev/name_of_device", "r");
// if (card == NULL) handle error ...
size_t count = fread(data, sizeof data, 1, card);
// if (count != 1) handle error ...
```

Comment: Weird. On my system, it is /dev/mmc... Is your udev outdated?

Comment: @SergeyA, more likely it is a difference between what you and I interpret a "memory card" to be.  But the specific device name is really not the point.

Comment: @JohnBollinger                                                                                                             Disk /dev/sdc: 29.3 GiB, 31457280000 bytes, 61440000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x157d53fa                                                                                                 and i have fopen like this  FILE *card = fopen("/dev/sdc", "r");                                 and   size_t f = fread(data, sizeof data, 1, card);                                                                here f will return 1

Comment: Are you asking, @SayedMurad, or telling?  If the latter, then do you find something about that to be unexpected?